# Login users only if they meet the condition - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

**I was wondering where should i put the condition so if a user has status of 1, he can login but if he has not status of 1 he gets redirected back with error message?**

I will provide you any code you want from controllers etc.

Comment: Yes, the code would actually help.

Comment: In your `AppServiceProvider.php`, use `boot` function.

Comment: what code would u need so u can show me where and how to put the condition

Comment: @TalhaF. and how would the code look like? i want users to login if status=1 and if status !=1 redirect back with error

Comment: i have done the email verify and all that the status is in the ddatabase default 0, when they verify it goes status = 1

Answer (score 2):

It's clear if you read section [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users) of the official documentation:

> If you wish, you may also add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we may verify that user is marked as "active":
>
> ```php
> if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) > {
>     // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
> }
> ```

Comment: and where should i put this condition? In login controller or somewhere else?

Comment: Usually in the controller, yes.

Comment: i should make a function and place it on the login form that redirects users?

Comment: because now its only protected $redirectTo='/home'

Comment: Thanks i will, just is it possible to help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using laravel's built in authentication for a login form. You can read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

Comment: i have done the email verification to make the users status = 1, i just need a condition if a user has the default status which is 0, to not let them login

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
if(auth()->user->status == 0){
   return redirect()->route('login');
}
```